# Pass list of strings from Python requests to JSP Page

Tags: python, java, jsp

I want to send a list of strings in a post request from Python to JSP and convert it to an array / ArrayList server-side.

Python possible code:

```
requests.post(URL, data={'data':['a','b','c','d']})
```

I need to now parse it server-side, if possible without use of external libraries like Gson, Jackson and such.

I can also pass the data in a different way, if there is a builtin Java option to parse it afterwards.